# concatenate after in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, concatenation

I have an array of strings.

For e.g. `column_list=["ab","bc","cd","asv_a","asv_f","asv_l","asv_x", "xy","yz"]`.

Now I have another array with only the`"asv_"` value(which can be repeated or unique).

For e.g. `new_column = ["asv_b", "asv_f", "asv_s"]`.

Now I want to create a new array by concatenating the `new_column` array to `column_list` such that all the `asv_` values be together in the middle and unique.

**Expected outcome -**

```
result = ["ab","bc","cd","asv_a","asv_f","asv_l","asv_x","asv_b", "asv_s", "xy","yz"]
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: what is the attempted code?

Comment: added the expected outcome in question

Comment: What determines the insertion point? How did you determine that `new_column` would be inserted at index 7?

Comment: it's not about the insertion point. My new_column will also have `asv_` only. And there always going be some `asv_` in the middle of the column_list array. I just want to add a unique `asv_` from the new_column to that of column_list at the end(after `asv_` of column_list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of `asv_*` values in `column_list` for use in eliminating duplicates

```js
const asvValues = new Set(column_list.filter(v => v.startsWith("asv_")));
```

Then filter out duplicates

```js
const inserts = new_column.filter(v => !asvValues.has(v));
```

Now, find the index of the last `asv_` entry

```js
const lastAsv = column_list.lastIndexOf([...asvValues].pop());
```

Now use [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to insert the filtered array after the position found

```js
column_list.splice(lastAsv + 1, 0, ...inserts);
```

```js
const column_list=["ab","bc","cd","asv_a","asv_f","asv_l","asv_x", "xy","yz"];
const new_column = ["asv_b", "asv_f", "asv_s"];

const asvValues = new Set(column_list.filter((v) => v.startsWith("asv_")));
const inserts = new_column.filter((v) => !asvValues.has(v));
const lastAsv = column_list.lastIndexOf([...asvValues].pop());
column_list.splice(lastAsv + 1, 0, ...inserts);

console.log(column_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use method `mergedArr` to create an array with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to keep the order and then with [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to build the `result` as a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of unique values

Code:

```js
const column_list = ["ab","bc","cd","asv_a","asv_f","asv_l","asv_x", "xy","yz"]
const new_column = ["asv_b", "asv_f", "asv_s"]
const mergedArr = (arr, newArr) => Object
  .values(
    arr.reduce(
      (a, c, i) => (a[c.startsWith('asv_') ? 1 : !a[1].length ? 0 : 3].push(c), a), 
      [[], [], newArr, []]
    )
  )
  .flat()
  
const result = [...new Set(mergedArr(column_list, new_column))]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I don't want to change the order of any value before `asv_` and after `asv_` in `column_list`. 
Keeping the order same, I need to insert the `asv_` from new_column in the middle only

Comment: looking for something like if I found `asv_' in column_list insert unique values from new_column after that.